# React Application: Protect Development URLs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, security, webpack

I am working within a React application that currently houses development endpoints within it's index.js file.  These endpoints are required for authentication, data retrievals, and basic CRUD related functionalities that the application is dependent on.  For example, all calls start with an enpoint:

`export const ROOT_URL = https://dev4work.testsite.io/`;

Again, for clarity, we have incorporated redux which will then take this root endpoint, utilize different parameters and queries, in action creators called within a lifecycle method.

**However, I was wondering if there was a way to protect these endpoints from possible security breaches.**  Currently, they would be exposed in my bundle.js/manifest.js file.

I tried to research and was unable to determine the best strategy to code this.  Would I need to do configuration in webpack?  Create a .env file to house the endpoints?  Please let me know your thoughts or strategies that you implement.

Comment: At the end of the day the URL will be present in the final bundle passed to the browser. You could implement your own server and hide it there and proxy the requests to the API if it is sensitive and requires authentication.

Comment: Use something like [_dotenv_](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and a replace plugin (like [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#usage) for webpack) in your build pipeline. Then, use `process.env.ROOT_URL` in your code, only exposing the real URL used in the final bundle.